# Seemingly random errors when loading powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a script I've been working on for the past several months at work that automates the configuration process for a system we work on. The main script imports the other required "utility" scripts and runs the main loop. One of the scripts it imports is a form script which handles the form creation, display, etc. There are two versions of the script - one for a laptop and one for a desktop which we have designated as a server. While developing for the laptop version, I had no issues relating to the problem I will be describing. However, when first testing the server version on our test machine, I started getting some weird errors. The weird part is that it is always inconsistent. Sometimes there are no errors, and sometimes there are between 2 and 4 errors. I think it's also important to note I don't get these errors when running the script from the powershell ISE, only when running via a batch file that loads the script.

Some of the errors that I received are the following:

`Exception setting "Size": "Cannot convert the "System.Drawing.Size get_MinimumSize()" value of type "System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo" to type "System.Drawing.Size"."`

and

`Exception setting "Margin": "Cannot convert the "System.Drawing.Size" value of type "System.Management.Automation.Language.TypeName" to type "System.Windows.Forms.Padding"."`

These particular errors are from the lines that are changing the settings on a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` object (the Size and Margin values).

With my limited experience with Powershell, I narrowed it down to what I think is happening. At the beginning of the script, the `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` classes are added with the `Add-Type -AssemblyName...` line. That was the line I saw on several tutorials to be able to actually create and use the .NET forms. Just based on mostly guessing, I just added in a `Start-Sleep` command of 5 seconds to see what would happen. Lo and behold, that seemed to fix the error. At least, when I tried running from the .bat file about 10-20 times, I didn't get the error.

The main question I have is what is actually going on? I want to make sure these errors don't ever pop up again and I'm not confident the "fix" I implemented will ensure that. It doesn't seem to make sense that it does because if it is actually a problem with the classes not loading, I would assume/hope that Powershell would generate some kind of error.I'm also wondering why I never saw these errors when running the script on the laptop version. I wouldn't know where to begin to see what difference between the two would cause this error, but it's still interesting to me

Comment: You do **.Dispose()** the form when done after `$form.ShowDialog()` don't you? If not, repeated showing of the form without disposing of it will cause problems

Comment: ISE development work lends itself to issues like this, as most variables defined in it will last until the ISE is closed.  To make sure this isn't happening, you could open new ISE windows every hour or so to try and spot errors like this earlier.  `Add-type` commands are synchronous.  PowerShell won't move to the next line till `Add-Type` completes.  The delay sounds like a red-herring (not the real error)

Comment: @Theo yes I do.

Comment: Please show us the relevant part of your code. The errors you show can have various reasons, but without the code it is impossible to pinpoint.

Answer (score 0):

if possible share the code (or parts of it) as of now we have to assume a lot which might just not be true.

anyways, here is my thought "cannot convert ..." errors as of my experience. I also had this error when trying to assign a value to a specific variable but of another type.

the solution for me was: just before assigning the new value I removed the variable like `Remove-Variable Size` (note: there is no `$` in front of the variable name!)

another solution might be to specify the type on assignment like `[System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo]$Size = WhateverYourCodeIs`

Comment: The lines that I mentioned in the original post that are getting errors are pretty straightforward. One of them is `$cboVariable.Size = $cboSize`. And `$cboSize` is set to a `System.Drawing.Size` object since it's used alot. When the form gets cleaned up, the form itself and all of its field get disposed. I will have to try your method